# Llamar modal desde otra página

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

Tengo varios modales en una solo página. Los quiero incluir en un menú que es común para todas las páginas. Quiero, para no copiar, pegar y adaptarlo código, buscar una manera de llamar al modal que está en una página desde otra página.

Intenté con esta manera

```
<button type="button" href="ubicacion.php" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
```

Pero en la documentación de Bootstrap dice que a partir de la version 3.3.0 ya no funciona más esta forma.

> This option is deprecated since v3.3.0 and has been removed in v4. We recommend instead using client-side templating or a data binding framework, or calling jQuery.load yourself.
>
> If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded one time via jQuery's load method and injected into the .modal-content div. If you're using the data-api, you may alternatively use the href attribute to specify the remote source. An example of this is shown below:

No sé cómo usaría la función load para este problema.

Este es la parte del menú que quiero que se abra el modal.

```
<li><a href="#">Abrir modal</a></li>
```

Y mi modal que está en otra página (pasajeros/index.php)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Añadir nuevo pasajero</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            Mi modal

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            Footer modal
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto no tiene nada que ver con PHP, por favor pon los tags adecuados.

Comment: usa un codigo que hice y un modal es con ajax y php https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05fuDZbqNIVMVhwTkl0S3pSVWs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hola Santiago, hay algunas cosas que no terminan de quedarme claras: ¿A qué te refieres con “llamar al modal que está en una página desde otra página”? ¿Donde se encuentra el modal y dónde quieres que se vea? ¿Has probado el ejemplo que hay en la página que citas? ¿Cómo no te funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Veo un pedacito de PHP por lo que me das a pensar que lo estas usando, puedes resolver este problema usando el **include** de PHP.

Aísla el Modal que quieres que sea "compartido" por los archivos HTML, veo que estas usando PHP, por lo que puedes hacer un include para el MODAL compartido.

Ejemplo (**modal.php**):

```
<?php
  echo '<div class="modal fade" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"> -
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document"> -
  etiquetado HTML -
  etiquetado HTML -
  etiquetado HTML';
 ?>
```

Ahora lo único que tienes que hacer es mandarlo a llamar en los HTML que lo necesites.

```
<?php include 'modal.php';?>
```

Si haces un cambio en modal.php, se reflejará en todos los lugares que lo estén usando, es decir, incluyendo.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia

Le proporongo lo siguiente *(Espero haber entendido su planteamiento)*:

Haciendo uso de Ajax (de jQuery) con [BootstrapDialog](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) en *función* que traiga el contenido de la modal:

```
function traeryMotrarModal([parametros si son necesarios]) {

    /* [parametros si son necesarios] deberás pasarlo en su parte
       respectiva ya sea necesario por GET o POST; en el ejemplo
       no los puse en ningun lado */

    $.ajax( {
        url:"pasajeros/index.php",
        cache:false, /* Evitamos cache */
        dataType: 'html', /* Se recibirá contenido HTML */
        success: function (data) {
                /* data es el HTML a insertar; deberás insertarlo
                   según como corresponda a la model que usas, a continuación
                   como yo la use usando BootstrapDialog (estructura básica). */;
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                /* Incluir ya sea fijo el título o colocarlo dentro de los parámetros de la función */
                title: "[titulo de la ventana]",
                message: data, /* aqui lo recibido (el HTML de la modal) */
                closeByBackdrop: false,
                closeByKeyboard: true,
                closable: true,
                size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_SMALL,
                type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_INFO,
                buttons: [
                        {
                            label: 'Guardar', /* Nombre del botón (en este caso "Guardar" */
                            action: function(dialogRef){

                                   /* Lo que se hara en caso de pulsar botón "guardar" */

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Cerrar', /* Nombre del botón (en este caso "Cerrar" */
                            action: function(dialogRef){
                                    dialogRef.close(); /* Cerrar la modal sin hacer nada más */
                            }
                        }
                ]
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              /* Acción en caso de fallar/error el/en ajax */
        }
    }
    );

} // traeryMotrarModal
```

Espero le sea de utilidad o de idea como hacerlo para la estructura de su proyecto.